# knit a word while Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

i am kniting a file into word,but this happens,please tell me why.
i'm not using icloud and the path names are english.And i'm a newbie using the R Markdown for the first time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o64G.png)

nothing,i just don't get any clues.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide a minimal reproducible example for your next questions, installing dev version of rmarkdown (`devtools::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')`) might help based on this [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1184)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.